# bootstrap progress bar background color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap progress bar as a health bar. So I use the class progress-bar-success to make the health green, but when the progress bar goes down I would like red "behind" the green. When I set the css background-color it turns the entire progress bar red. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="progress">
   <div id="divPlayerHealthBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;"></div>
   <div id="divPlayerHealth" class="overlay_health" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">@Model.Player.Health / @Model.Player.Health</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the container of the progress class to control the bg color behind the green. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rg7src44/2/

```
.progress-red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then add the class div container with class progress to also have progress-red using client script:

```
<div class="progress progress-red">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: ty sir that did it! Looks like I was adding it to the progress-bar div which is clearly wrong. Thanks!